# Имя не сущестует в данном контексте, хотя все существует

Tags: c#

```
WasapiLoopbackCapture capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

capture.Initialize();
```

VS 2017 пишет, что `capture` не существует в текущем контексте. В чем проблема?

Comment: Нет, из одного. Поменял, все равно не работает

Comment: да, прямо из кода копировал

Comment: Это код написан не в каком-либо методе, а вложен напрямую в класс - я гарантирую это.

Comment: @alexander да, так и есть. Спасибо